# offline map with routing

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

i am devoloping an app that use osmdroid map (Mapnik).PNG that working offline,and i will add to it routing if osmdroid will work with me and make routing .and if not which map to use instead of osmdroid.

Answer (score 2):

[Graphhopper](http://graphhopper.com/) is a routing engine that works online/offline and it based in [mapsforge](https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/), but im almost sure that Graphhopper can work under osm too.